# Is there a way to define the tsConfig import path on Jest?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, tsconfig

Is there a way to use the constant import path on a .spec/.test file?

I made the configuration on tsconfig.json to use relative path as @foldername/*

```
"rootDir": "./src",
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "paths": {
        "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
        "@config/*": ["config/*"],
        "@enum/*": ["enum/*"],
        "@handlers/*": ["handlers/*"],
        "@models/*": ["models/*"],
     },
```

Works perfectly on .ts file, i tried configure jest.config.ts but when i try import as "@models/..." didn't work properly

```
    "roots": ["<rootDir/src>"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^@models/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/models/$1"
    },
```

my folder structure is

```
src/
├─ models/controllers/.../
tsconfig.json
jest.config.ts
```